# uploading a file using google apis java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am uploading a file to google cloud storage using java. The uploaded may of any size. I am sending this file using post request to a bucket, but after the processing of the request i am getting the response like

**Metadata part is too large.**

I am using this URL as the post request from my jsp page.

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o?uploadType=multipart&name=hello&X-Upload-Content-Type=application/octet-stream

Can any one tell me how to upload the file using the above url?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?